# Problem with Java 8.45 instalation

Tags: software-installation, wine, java

I tried to install java 8.45 wine but the installation wont even start so I tried to download older version and update it but the update fails to download the patch.

Does anyone know what to do with it?

Comment: Java on wine? Please elaborate.

Comment: its because i need to run .exe program that uses java 8.45. It can't be executed without java nor wine.

Comment: isn't there *.jar file by any chance?

Comment: Link to software would be nice ;), so we can look at it closer ...

Answer (score -4):

**try this method**

1.Download java

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

2.Open terminal type commant

```
cd Downloads

tar xzvf jdk-8u45-linux-x64.tar.gz

sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm

sudo mv ~/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_45/ /usr/lib/jvm/

sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java" 0

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javac" 0

sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java

sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/javac

sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45
    export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

. ~/.bashrc

java -version

echo $JAVA_HOME

echo $PATH
```

Comment: The OP is trying to install Java inside wine. This is not relevant since it is a way to install on Linux itself.